# IIS 7 Redirect To SSL

Tags: iis-7, ssl, redirection

I have an intranet site, which is running on IIS 7. The site is accessible using both the FQDN (mysite.mydomain.mycompany) and by just "mysite".

The SSL certificate is signed for FQDN. It's installed and working fine if you were to visit https://mysite.mydomain.mycompany/ (Secure). Or if you access using non-secure short or long URL either http://mysite  or http://mysite.mydomain.mycompany via 403.4 redirect to the secure page.

The problem I'm running into is that when a user visits the site using https://mysite/ (secure, with short alias). IIS presents the user with the only certificate it has, for "mysite.mydomain.mycompany", which of course doesn't match the address typed in by the user and they get a SSL certificate warning.

Is there anyway for me to intercept a visit to "https://mysite" and redirect the users to https://mysite.mydomain.mycompany" before SSL handshake happens with mismatched certificate?

If not, what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot stop the `https://` request from completing an SSL handshake before a redirection could possibly be sent.

Since IIS can't do TLS Server Name Indication, probably the only effective solution for this would be to get a certificate with `mysite` as a Subject Alternate Name - a public certificate authority wouldn't issue this cert, so hopefully your cert is issued from an internal CA.